# Komodo php debugger stop at the beginning of script

Tags: php, debugging, komodo

I'm using Komodo IDE to debug PHP. It always stop at the beginning of a script although there is no breakpoint. Is there anyway to disable it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

go to menu Edit/Preferences/Debugger/, change the 'initial break behaviour' to 'Run to first breakpoint'